# How to use affinity key with BinaryObject

Tags: ignite

I want to use the affinity key with BinaryObject. I have used below code to set my affinity key but it didn't work. My Cache key is off type BinaryObject.

```
CacheKeyConfiguration keyConfiguration = new CacheKeyConfiguration(BinaryObject.class.getName(), affinityKeyConfig);
cfg.setKeyConfiguration(keyConfiguration);
```

I have used BinaryObject in key and value also. I have used bank as affinity key.  I had inserted 4 records for 'SBI' and 8 'records for 'HDFC'. For node 1, it should show 4/8 on primary/backup and for node 2, it should show 8/4 on primary/backup.
But I can see records are equally distributed. If I use affinity key then data should not distributed equally.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's your use case? BinaryObjects are mostly the underlying storage format. If your key is a Java class with the name PersonKey, you can _convert_ that to a BinaryObject, but you wouldn't say it's a binary object in the configuration.

Comment: I cannot use fixed Object as key because keys are dynamic so I used BinaryObject for key and value also. likeCacheConfiguration<BinaryObject, BinaryObject>